# UIButton not showing up in tableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to display a UILabel and a UIButton in my app, when the table is empty. However, it's only showing the label. I know that's because I'm only adding the label to the view. How do I add the button to the view as well?

```
    UILabel *messageLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];

    messageLabel.text = @"No data is currently available. Please pull down to refresh.";
    messageLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    messageLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    messageLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Palatino-Italic" size:20];
    [messageLabel sizeToFit];

    UIButton *messageButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    [messageButton addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(aMethod:)
                   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [messageButton setTitle:@"Add your first service"
                   forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    messageButton.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);

    [self.tableView addSubview:messageButton];
    [self.tableView addSubview:messageLabel];

    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't added messageButton to any view (or not in the code you have shown).

You need something like:

```
[self.tableView addSubview:messageButton];
[self.tableView addSubview:messageLabel];
```

Comment: This just shows me the button, but not the label :S

Comment: Have you added both of the lines ? The other thing could be that your views are overlapping ( You specified that you width and height is from self.view which can be over buttons place ). To fix this just reorder addSubviews.

Comment: Have you tried reordering ? First add Label then Button. 
   [self.tableView addSubview:messageLabel];
    [self.tableView addSubview:messageButton];

Comment: Can you hard code values in the first line :UILabel *messageLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];

Answer (score 2):

What you ***should*** be doing is dropping your UILabel and UIButton into your XIB or Storyboard, whatever holds the table view, connecting them to outlets and then hiding or showing them depending on if the table has any entries or not.

But yes, Nick's answer is also correct (and +1 to him).  Instead of doing "`self.tableView.backgroundView`", you should be doing "`[self.tableView addSubview:messageButton];`".

Comment: Yeah, I agree, it would be much better practice...
Also, note that user just set label, not button... so, to complete answer ( and I will change that in my answer ) should be [self.tableView addSubview:self.messageLabel];
[self.tableView addSubview:self.messageButton]

Comment: When I drop them in, they get added as a tablecell though, since the table fills the whole view.

Comment: Oh, you're using a "`UITableViewController`", aren't you? Maybe Nick's answer is the right way to go for the moment.  In my own code, I use a regular "`UIViewController`" with a table dropped in.  TableViewControllers really don't add anything compelling to an app, IMHO.

Comment: No, no, it's actually a `UIViewController` that is part of a `NavigationController`. So, the view consists of the navigationbar, table and toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a tableViewController you can use a normal viewController and add a tableview in it. Also add button and label in interface. Then set these item to hidden or not based on the elements of the tableview.

Answer (score 0):

Best is to use `viewForHeaderInSection` method of `UITableView` as your requirment is to use only when empty data so it will be displayed when its empty and removed automatically when has data

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  if([yourTblViewDataArray count] == 0)
  {
     //Add UILabel and UIButton in UIView 
     UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
     //here
     return view;
  }
  else
  {
     return nil;
  }
```

}

`HeightForHeaderInSection` of `UITableView` which is necessary should be added:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{ 
  //According to requirement size should vary
  if([yourTblViewDataArray count] == 0)
  {
     return 60.0f;
  }
  else
  {
     return 0.0f;
  }

}
```